# Current date function returning yesterday's date in JPA

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I'm trying to get results from MySQL database from JPA Repository with a *LESS THAN EQUAL TO* condition `<= CURRENT_DATE`. But the `CURRENT_DATE` function gives yesterday's date and thus my query does not work as expected.
However, running `curdate()` query on database level gives the correct result.
I have tried the same condition in a native query as well and the result is same.
Can anyone tell me why is that happening?
I've confirmed that the current date function is not giving the correct date by `@Query("select current_date from table where id=1")`.
Surprisingly, `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` and `now()` gives the correct date but when I try to extract date from it using `Date()`, same issue.
I need **Date** not timestamp for my condition.

Comment: What is the timezone your database and your server is running on?

Comment: It's the default: SYSTEM.

Comment: how does the generated SQL statement from Hibernate look like?

Comment: `select current_date as col_0_0_ from table t where t.id=1` for `@Query("select current_date from table where id=1")`

Comment: And what do you get when you execute this in mysql?

Comment: Correct current date.

Comment: So I assume that there is a timezone issue. You get 2020-04-24 and while putting in a Date it becomes 2020-04-23 23:00:00. Are you using java.util.Date or java.sql.Date? And why are you not using LocalDate?

Comment: No, no. I'm not using Java Date here. It's SQL Date() in the query. Like: `select Date(now())`.

Comment: Can you please show your code?

Comment: ```@Query(value ="select Date(now()) from dual", nativeQuery = true)
    String getCurDate();```

Comment: ```@Query("select current_date from table where id=1")
    String getCurDate();```

Comment: Both give the yesterday date.

Comment: How do you connect to your database. And what Timezone ha your database?